# Swapping the first two word of every line without using sed

Tags: text-processing

I want to know if there is a way to easier way to swap the first two words of every line.

Let say my text file consist of these three lines:

```
 Mary Joe
 William Edward
 Shawn Liam
```

Ultimately I want this:

```
 Joe Mary 
 Edward William
 Liam Shawn
```

I know this can be done by sed command by doing this:

```
sed -e "s/\([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]*\)/\2 \1 /g" file
```

But thats to much to remember.

Is there an easier way to do this.

This is bash btw.

Comment: If your version of sed supports extended regular expression syntax, you can simplify that somewhat e.g. `sed -E 's/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/\2 \1/'`. Note that the `g` modifier is not required if you want to swap only the *first* two columns of each line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With two word lines, this might be easier:

```
awk '{print $2,$1}' file
```

If you need to swap the first two words of a file with or without two words per line:

```
awk 'NF >= 2{t=$2;$2=$1;$1=t};{print}' file
```

Note that this will collapse multiple spaces into one.

Comment: that first command is way easier, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your words are space delimited, then `awk` can be easier:

```
awk 'NF > 1 {a = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = a};1' <file
```